# Linhas com mesma altura em tabela no Latex

Tags: latex

Eu preciso reproduzir em Latex uma tabela com 3 colunas e 5 linhas. Ela deve usar toda a largura do parágrafo, centralizar o conteúdo das células tanto horizontal como verticalmente e auto ajustar textos mais longos. Mas, principalmente, precisa ter *a mesma altura para todas as linhas*.

Eu utilizei o `tabularx` (pra ter mais facilmente a tabela na largura do parágrafo), redefini o tipo da coluna X para centralizar o conteúdo das células na horizontal e vertical e cheguei a esse resultado:

**Código com Exemplo Mínimo Compilável**

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

% Redefine a coluna do tipo X para centralizar horizontal e verticalmente seu conteúdo
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}} 

\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
            \hline
            Linha 1 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. & Aenean suscipit, nunc ac sodales bibendum, massa lacus iaculis augue, ut suscipit mauris libero in velit. \\
            \hline

            Linha 2 & Vivamus quis justo ac elit condimentum molestie. & Etiam ultrices a libero sed semper. \\
            \hline

            Linha 3 & Morbi ultrices sodales justo, et dictum quam sodales eget. & Cras tortor libero, volutpat eget erat eu, blandit tempus nunc. \\
            \hline              

            Linha 4 & Pellentesque gravida, odio sed aliquet tempus, metus lectus sodales sapien. & Fusce fermentum malesuada eros. \\
            \hline              

            Linha 5 &  Etiam commodo interdum dictum. In sit amet semper leo. In non auctor mauris. & Vivamus ultrices augue non enim pulvinar feugiat. \\
            \hline                                      
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Tabela Resultante**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só não consegui ainda deixar todas as linhas com a mesma altura (idealmente a da primeira linha, visto que foi o mínimo possível para incluir o conteúdo da célula mais à direita). Já tentei [especificar espaçamento adicional ao final de cada linha](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19594/39148), mas essa solução requer muita tentativa e erro e o resultado final não é bom porque adiciona espaços apenas na última coluna. Tentei também [usar o pacote `easytable`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87236/39148), mas ele não permite fixar a largura do parágrafo e acaba extrapolando os limites da página, além de também não fazer a quebra automática de textos longos. E, finalmente, tentei também fazer [a alteração do espaçamento vertical (ou *arraystretch*)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31681/39148), mas o resultado não foi o esperado porque aparentemente esse comando só aumenta a margem interna das células e não garante que as linhas tenham a mesma altura.

Alguém tem alguma solução pra esse problema?

Comment: Há um site próprio para TeX.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Eu sei (tanto que até mesmo referenciei na própria pergunta algumas informações diretamente de lá). Apenas preferi postar a pergunta aqui pra estimular conteúdo de TeX no SOPt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como voce tambem usou, o pacote `tabularx` e melhor para lidar com tabelas com linhas grandes, ja que faz o *line break* sozinho.

Para conseguir todas as celulas da mesma altura eu usei o comando `\parbox`. Esse comando cria um paragrafo dentro de uma caixa e a sintaxe geral e:

```
\parbox[pos][height][contentpos]{width}{text}
```

`pos` pode ser `b,c` ou `t` e controla o alinhamento da caixa, relativo a linha base do texto. `height` e a altura, o que eu usei para controlar a altura de cada celula. `contentpos` controla a posicao do texto, o que eu sei usei para deixar centralizado com o `c`. `width` e o tamanho da caixa. Como estamos dentro da tabela, `\linewidth` e 1/3 da linha, ja que temos 3 colunas. Depois vem o texto.

Um `parbox` e basicamente uma `minipage`.

Ficou bem grande sua tabela exemplo, contudo :P

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{.85\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
\parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Linha 1}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering  Aenean suscipit,
  nunc ac sodales bibendum, massa lacus iaculis augue, ut suscipit
  mauris libero in velit.}\\
\hline
\parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Linha 2}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Vivamus quis justo ac elit condimentum molestie.}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Etiam ultrices a
  libero sed semper.}\\
\hline
\parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Linha 3}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Morbi ultrices sodales justo, et dictum quam sodales eget.}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Cras tortor libero,
  volutpat eget erat eu, blandit tempus nunc.}\\
\hline
\parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Linha 4}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Pellentesque
  gravida, odio sed aliquet tempus, metus lectus sodales sapien.}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Fusce fermentum
  malesuada eros.}\\
\hline
\parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Linha 5}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Etiam commodo interdum dictum. In sit amet semper leo. In non auctor mauris.}
& \parbox[b][\linewidth][c]{\linewidth}{\centering Vivamus ultrices
  augue non enim pulvinar feugiat.}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Gera:

[image: Tabela gerada com o codigo acima]

[Referencias sobre o `parbox` na wikipedia](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#minipage_and_parbox).